# Is this the way I'm supposed to be use mod_rewrite or do I have redundant lines?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here's what I have:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot D:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\mysites\tupega.com
   ServerName tupega.tld

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on  
    RewriteRule ^/nuevoanuncio$ /create/nuevoanuncio.php    
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on    
    RewriteRule ^/registrar$ /create/nuevousuario.php
    </IfModule> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Do I have to create a new `<IfModule>` for every rewrite I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can put all your rules in one [`<IfModule>` block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/nuevoanuncio$ /create/nuevoanuncio.php
    RewriteRule ^/registrar$ /create/nuevousuario.php
</IfModule>
```

The `<IfModule>` block is only used to avoid errors when mod_rewrite is not available.